# Python3: Расчёт контрольной суммы bytearray() с помощью порождающего полинома?

Tags: python, c++

Имеется

```
b=bytearray.fromhex("10 01 00 81 10 1f 1d 10 02 09 30 09 30 36 31 0c 10 03")
```

Для этого массива хочу добавить в конец контрольную сумму.

```
sumcrc = CRC(b, len)
b.append(sumcrc)
```

Есть код на C++ контрольной суммы:

```
int CRC (char *msg, int len)
{
    int crc,j;
    crc = 0;
    msg++;
    msg++;
    while ( len-- > 0 )
    {
        crc = crc ^ (int) *msg++ << 8;
        for ( j=0; j < 8; j++ )
        {
            if(crc & 0x8000) crc = (crc << 1) ^ 0x1021;
            else crc <<= 1;
        }
    }
    return crc;
}
```

Подскажите, как изящнее реализовать на питоне подсчёт?

Comment: Изящнее всего - взять готовую реализацию из стандартной библиотеки: https://docs.python.org/3/library/binascii.html#binascii.crc_hqx